# phpmailer - adding dynamic `$mail->From` value results in unsent mail

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I'm getting the "From" email dynamically through a form that gets populated on page load using `$email = $_POST['company_email'];` When I add the variable to the line `$mail->From` in phpmailer the script runs successfully, but no mail is received. If I enter a value statically (eg test@email.com), it works and the Reply To email even displays the dynamic address.

I've narrowed it down to just being the `$mail->From` line that causes the issue. Has anyone run into this before?

I'm using PHPMailer as is: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

I've simplified it down to almost nothing for testing purposes:

```
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$to = $_POST['send_to'];
$company_name = $_POST['company_name'];
$company_email = $_POST['company_email'];
$email_type = $_POST['email_type'];
$subject = '';

$mail->From = 'from@email.com'; // <-- this is the line that's causing the issue
// when changed to $company_email, no mail is received
$mail->FromName = $company_name;
$mail->addAddress($to);               // Name is optional
$mail->addReplyTo($company_email, $company_name);

$mail->Subject = $subject; //'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
```

**EDIT:**
I've found that it doesn't like yahoo email addresses. I left the email address the same, only changed "yahoo" to "mail" and then "gmail" and it worked. Is the server seeing the yahoo address as spam then?

Comment: probably getting killed as spam, because your webserver is sending email masquerading as something else.e .g. your server's hostname is "foo-1-2-3-4.hostingco.com", yet is sending email claiming to be "from: someone@example.com". since @hostingco.com isn't listed as a valid source of example.com emails, boom... spam.

Comment: *"I've found that it doesn't like yahoo email addresses."* - Maybe Yahoo's blacklisted your server; hard to say but it's a possibility.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks for the direction. I'll look into it more.

Comment: To add; what with the new [Canadian Anti-Spam Law](http://fightspam.gc.ca/), someone may have marked some of your messages as Spam, that's if Emails are sent to Canadians; just saying and not implying that you're a spammer. It's getting worse out there, and these are things we Canadians are faced in dealing with.

Comment: I fixed the project link - you had linked to my personal fork rather than the official one. Yahoo doesn't check SPF, but it goes very heavy on DKIM and DMARC, adn in general you won't be able to send mail that says it's from a yahoo domain from anything but a yahoo server.

Comment: If you want more feedback on what's happening at send time, set `$mail->SMTPDebug = 3;`

Comment: lol Fred, thanks for the info and @Synchro Thank you for being so helpful.